# Django act as browser

Tags: python, django, http

Im lately working on a POC of mine. My goal is to forward the request from an user to another server and act as a kind browser in a browser.

```
def test(request):
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

with this code i recieve a normal response (without css, but not that important rn), but i cant really use the site (makes sense, because im not really using their backend.) Is there a simple way to kinda act as an browser in django so that i could for example edit the recieved code?

EDIT: to sum it up: i want to forward every nessesary traffic between the user an me, so that the user can completly interact with the 2nd server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web proxy in python/django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494998/web-proxy-in-python-django)

Comment: not really... I'm not just trying to display the response, i want to forward all the users actions to the 2nd server, so that the user can use the site. When i try to stream the site or use the code shown above, i can't use buttons or hrefs.